# ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:

Tags: rosdep, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

When I am running  $ rosdep install humanoid_msgs nao_robot nao_common

I will get this Error :

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
nao_teleop: Missing resource joy
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/mk/fuerte_workspace/nao
ROS path [2]=/home/mk/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot
ROS path [3]=/home/mk/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [6]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

Is there any solution ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64462/error:-the-following-packages/stacks-could-not-have-their-rosdep-keys-resolved-to-system-dependencies:/) by [Mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/4999/mohsen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package joy is missing.

Search in ROS for the package JOY

and Install it.

Check for dependencies using,

rosdep install joy and install if any.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2